# Converting Integer values to Date in Presto SQL

Tags: date, presto, dbeaver

Below is a script i am trying to run in Presto; Subtracting today's date from an integer field I am attempting to convert to date. To get the exacts days between. Unfortunately, it seems the highlighted block does not always convert the date correctly and my final answer is not correct. Please does anyone know another way around this or a standard method on presto of converting integer values to date.
Interger value in the column is in the format '20191123' for year-month-date

```
select ms, activ_dt, current_date, date_diff('day',act_dt,current_date) from 
(   
select ms,activ_dt, **CAST(parse_datetime(CAST(activ_dt AS varchar), 'YYYYMMDD') AS date) as act_dt**, nov19 
from h.A_Subs_1 where msisdn_key=23480320012
) limit 19
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert "date as a number" (eg. `20180527` for May 27, 2018) using the following:

1. cast to varchar
2. `parse_datetime` with appropriate format
3. cast to date (since `parse_datetime` returns a `timestamp`)

Example:

```
presto> SELECT CAST(parse_datetime(CAST(20180527 AS varchar), 'yyyyMMdd') AS date);
   _col0
------------
 2018-05-27
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample query for your requirement:

```
select date_diff('day', date_parse('20191209', '%Y%m%d'), current_timestamp);
```